# Android BottomNavigation fragment show/hide after App (screen) rotate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to simulate App (screen) rotate, but after the screen is rotated, the BottomNavigation fragments won't work anymore.

I have the following Array / vars

```java
private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[]{new HomeFragment(), new MapFragment(), new SavedFragment(), new NotificationsFragment()};
private int selected = -1;
```

In `onCreateView` I am calling...

```java
// open first Fragment when app starts
if (savedInstanceState == null) switchFragment(0, ShoutsHomeFragment.TAG); 
else selected = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_FRAGMENT);
```

`switchFragment` looks like

```java
private void switchFragment(int index, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    // creating for the first time
    if (fragment == null) transaction.add(R.id.tab_fragment_container, fragments[index], tag);
    if (selected >= 0) transaction.hide(fragments[selected]);   // <--- don't work
    if (fragment != null) transaction.show(fragment);           // <--- don't work
    transaction.commit();
    selected = index;
}
```

So, `transaction.hide` and `transaction.show` is not working after rotating the screen, it stays on the same Fragment when I tap on other items on the BottomNavigation

```java
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_shouts_home:
            switchFragment(0, HomeFragment.TAG);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_heat_map:
            switchFragment(1, MapFragment.TAG);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_loved:
            switchFragment(2, SavedFragment.TAG);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            switchFragment(3, NotificationsFragment.TAG);
            return true;
}
```

```java
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_FRAGMENT, selected);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I programmed it this way so that I can retain Fragments (scroll) position when switching between items on BottomNavigation. So I want to `show/hide` instead of creating new Instance every time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) check out this doc. I hope this will help you

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers the problem is not with `selected` but with `transaction.hide` and `transaction.show`

Comment: try with transaction.replace() funcation and check

Comment: add this in your manifest.xml file under activity tag


`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

Comment: add in to saveinstancestate and restore instance state your code need to execute that sit nothing else in this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate the screen, all of your activities and all of your non-retained fragments are put through the whole lifecycle. This means your `private Fragment[] fragments...` is also recreated. Your Fragments in your list are no longer the fragments in the `FragmentManager`. This means hide is not going to work the way you have it being called and the top-most Fragment will always be the one that is visible. If you use the TAG method, it will probably work.

```
String getFragmentTagByIndex(final int index) {
    switch (index) {
       // Make return tag.
    }
}

{
// inside switchFragment
    final Fragment visibleFragment = transaction.findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTagByIndex(selected));
    transaction.hide(visibleFragment);
}
```

You are essentially trying to implement a `ViewPager` with a [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) I would recommend you use the FragmentPagerAdapter